# Non Riemannian Manifolds and Failure of the Usual Dot Product to induce a Riemannian Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ denote a smooth manifold. Let $X = X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $Y=Y^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ be smooth vector fields on $M$. We can pointwise define an inner product via the usual dot product. This gives us a smooth map $p \rightarrow \Sigma X^i(p)Y^i(p)$ for $p \in M$.

To me, this seems to imply that the usual dot product always induces a Riemannian metric, contradicting the existence of non-Riemannian manifolds.

Can someone point out the error in the above reasoning?

Comment: This inner product depends on the chart, and will not be defined globally. What do you mean by "non-Riemannian manifold" ? Vector bundles over paracompact base spaces always carry riemannian structures.

Comment: I'm not sure where the above reasoning is dependent on paracompactness.

Answer (score 1):

Olivier has pointed out in the comment that the dot product the OP wrote down is not invariant under change of coordinates and has thus answered the question.